# Having Trouble Printing During Loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

Noob question because I am new to Python but I am working on a side project where each of these voltages (0.3, 0.32, etc) are used as an input, and then that input generates a probability in an output file.

**This is the output I'm looking for:**

> Input: 0.3 Probability = 7.509
>
> Input 0.32 Probability = 1.399
>
> Input 0.34 Probability = 2.773
>
> Input 0.36 Probability = 0.127
>
> ...

**This is the output I'm getting:**

> 0.3
>
> Probability = 7.509
>
> 0.3
>
> Probability = 1.399
>
> 0.3
>
> Probability = 2.773
>
> 0.3
>
> Probability = 0.127

I'm **having trouble** putting the **print(str(voltage))** statement in the right location to get the output that I want... As you can see, it is repeating the voltage over and over.

**Here's the code, thank you for your time I appreciate you:**

```
prob=[]

voltages = [0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5]
for voltage in voltages:
    update_code(voltage)
    os.system("hspice pbit.sp >output.txt")
    def search():
        with open('output.txt') as f:
            datafile = f.readlines()
        for line in datafile:
            if 'probability' in line:
                prob.append(line)
                return True
        return False
    if search():
        for voltage in voltages:
            for items in prob:
                print(str(voltage))
                print(items)
        else:
            print('False')
```

Comment: I think the issue might be that you defined the function within the loop, and you are looping over voltages within a loop of voltages itself.

Comment: Aside from the marked duplicate, you have a separate issue in that `search` can only `return` once, and thus will only ever `.append` one item to `prob`. Instead of having `search` return a boolean, just check whether there are any items in `prob` after calling it. Better yet, instead of using a global for `prob`, make `search` return it.

Comment: I also don't understand what the outermost loop is for. It would help to explain in more detail what the *actual overall problem you are trying to solve* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `zip` function so that you can print both the voltage and the probability side by side. Please note that both lists should have the same size to avoid any bugs.

```
for voltage, item in zip(voltages, prob):
    line = "Input: " + str(voltage) + " Probability: " + item
    print(line)
```